# Compressão de dados em C

Tags: c, compressão

Preciso Implementar um programa em C que faz a criação de arquivos compactados a partir de arquivos texto (por exemplo, códigos-fonte de programas C, entre outros). Esta compactação será realizada com a utilização do método de compactação Run Length Encoding. O programa deve ter um menu com 3 opções, conforme abaixo:

1 - Fazer a compressão -> grava um novo arquivo com os dados comprimidos
2 - Desfazer a compressão -> grava um novo arquivo com os dados descomprimidos
3 - Sair

Preciso da ajuda

Comece um pouco abaixo, mas falta muito.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 int op;
 char conteudo[1110];
 FILE *pf;
 long tamanho;

do{

    system("cls");
 printf("#######################################################\n");
    printf("       |   Escolha a opcao desejada            |\n");
    printf("       | 1 - Fazer Compressao.                 |\n");
    printf("       | 2 - Desfazer a compressao             |\n");
    printf("       | 3 - Sair                              |\n");

  printf("############################################################\n");

    printf("Informe a opcao desejada: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    if(op != 3){
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                    pf = fopen("teste.txt", "r");

                    if(pf == NULL){
                        printf("ERRO!!");
                        getch();
                    }else{
                        fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
                        tamanho = ftell(pf);
                        printf("O arquivo possui %ld bytes", tamanho);
                        getch();
                    }

                break;
            case 2:

                if(pf == NULL){
                    printf("Não foi possível abrir arquivo");
                }else{
                    fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
                    tamanho = ftell(pf);

                    pf = fopen("teste.txt", "rb");
                    fread(&conteudo, sizeof(char), 1110, pf);
                    printf("\n%s", conteudo);
                    getch();
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalida!\n\n\n");
                getch();
        }
    }

}while(op != 3);
fclose(pf);
}
```

O texto o arquivo txt pode ser algo tipo wwwwwwwwwwwwrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr999999999999999999997777777

Comment: Cara, esse codigo é bem complexo para postar como resposta aqui. De uma olhada aqui que tem um exemplo de como fazer. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding/C

Comment: oii! Eu até vi este exemplo, mas ele não puxa os dados no arquivo txt. Tem alguma ideia de mudança?